# How to return this value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a mobile app using `phonegap`, `jQuery` and `jQuery mobile`. I want to use `SqLite` database in my app for storing some user information. (I can't use `local storage` i want to do search/sort operations on the data)

This is the code I am working on to get this done,

```
function getAccountInformation(){
    var accounts = {};
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM account;', [], 
            function(transaction, result) { 
                if (result != null && result.rows != null) { 
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                        var item={};
                        var row = result.rows.item(i); 
                        for(var prop in row){
                            item[prop]=row[prop]
                        }
                        accounts[i]=item;
                    }
                }
            },errorHandler
        );
    },errorHandler,nullHandler);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(accounts));
}
```

If I put this `console.log(JSON.stringify(accounts));` after the end `}` of the `for loop` it shows proper output.

But if I put it where it is right now the `{}` is printed as an output.

How can I make `getAccountInformation()` function return that `accounts` object to my other function? Where I will use `jQuery` to render the output.

What I want to do is return this `accounts` object simply by wrting
`return accounts;`

Comment: Its just a simple function in which I will iterate over this returned object using `for in` loop just to add new elements to the `DOM`. It has nothing to do with this problem :)

Comment: you can simply call the other function after the end `}` of the `for` loop. Ex: `otherFunction(accounts);`

Comment: Thats what I do not want to do... :)
The function to be called is not always the same. It will differ based on the scenario. What I am trying to do is to make this `getAccountInformation()` function generic. If I call one function within this function then my entire new architecture will be of no use..

Comment: Ok i see, in this case you can pass the function, you want to call, as an argument to the `getAccountInformation(callBackFunction)` generic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the SqLite functions are asynchronous you cannot just return the value.

I would make the getAccountInformation receiving a callback as below:

```
function getAccountInformation(callbackfn)
{
    db.transaction(function(transaction),
        .....,
        function (transaction, result)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
               callbackfn(result);
            }
        });
}
```

In such way you will get your function called when the db request executed.

Comment: I understand that :)... Callbackfn is not always the same. It will change depending on the scenario. The way elements are shown on each page varies.. So I just want to somehow get this object back. Or i have to redesign the whole thing :(

Comment: Thanks, Solved it using your method. :)
Just one correction. you can't call the callback function as `callbackfn(result)`
Since we are passing function name as a string, we must use it like
`window[callbackfn](result);`

Comment: That's if you will really pass a function name. But you can also pass a function itself. E.g.

function processResult(result)
{
  //do something
}

getAccountInformation(processResult);

In this case you passes the function, not name and can call it directly.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on when the function is called. When it is called asynchronously (like an AJAX request) you're out of luck. In that case I suggest you read about [jQuery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

A code snippet based on deferreds could look like this:

```
var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();
var accounts = {};

deferred.done(function(data) {
    // process your data here
});

db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM account;', [], 
        function(transaction, result) { 
            if (result != null && result.rows != null) { 
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    var item={};
                    var row = result.rows.item(i); 
                    for(var prop in row){
                        item[prop]=row[prop]
                    }
                    accounts[i]=item;
                }
                deferred.resolve(accounts); // let the "done" function get called
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        }, errorHandler
    );
},errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. In the calling function, I am still receiving it as `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`db.transaction` and `transaction.executeSql` produce their results **asynchronously** through the use of callback functions. This means that your `getAccountInformation` function will return immediately and will not wait for the transaction to complete (as in a synchronous call).

It's probably easier to simply pass in a callback function as an argument of your `getAccountInformation` and run that function when the `accounts` array is populated. Therefore, change your function signature to `getAccountInformation(callback)` and replace the `executeSql` callback with:

```
        function(transaction, result) { 
            if (result != null && result.rows != null) { 
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    var item={};
                    var row = result.rows.item(i); 
                    for(var prop in row){
                        item[prop]=row[prop]
                    }
                    accounts[i]=item;
                }
                callback(accounts); // Call callback function with populated accounts
            }
        }
```

You can then call this function with:

```
getAccountInformation(function(accounts) {
    // Do something with the accounts
});
```

There are fancier ways such as jQuery Deferreds and Promises which makes working with asynchronous functions easier, but you still need to understand *why* this exists. By using asynchronous actions, your application stays responsive while waiting for results.